# Regex to remove hostname from image

Tags: css, regex

I want to remove the hostname from all the background css declarations I have in a html page

ie

```
<div style="background:transparent url(http://www.some-domain.com/images/test.png) no-repeat"></div>
```

to become

```
<div style="background:transparent url(images/test.png) no-repeat"></div>
```

Any ideas guys?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this something that can only be done in your favourite text editor or are the tags dynamically generated with some server side script?

Comment: `http://images/test.png` isn't a valid URL. Besides, why can't you do this by hand or with search/replace in a text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the regex "http://[^/]*" with "/".

Comment: Thanks a lot and all of the guys for the posts

Answer (score 0):

http://(.*?)images

If you do a regex replace, you can then remove the match and you should be ok.

Comment: Hi. The thing is that I want to replace just the URLs of the background declarations and nothing else (ie a links, form actions etc). Thanks

Comment: I see, for the whole page you'd need, then do the replace with that.
background:\w*\s*url\(http://(.*?)images/test.png\)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
(http:\/\/\w.*\/)
```

and replace the matched pattern with `/`

### [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/0P2WbwFTpw)